# How to pass multiple parameter in where condition in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have a query to get the order details like below:

```
    declare @orderNo nvarchar(10) = '12345'
    begin
    select * from orderProperty where CorderID =(select id from Corder where orderno = @orderNo)
    End
```

Its working fine for single order.

However, if I have multiple order numbers ( lets say, 3000) ; How can I get all data in a single query - by passing multiple parameters( that is multiple order numbers) into it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a table type parameter. Also, you'll need to switch to an `EXISTS` or `IN`.

Comment: but, the different orders will give different ID. Any example please? with 3-4 sample /example orders?

Comment: Bookmark Erland's website as it contains much useful information - and start with [arrays and list](https://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Comment: *"Any example please?"* The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) has plenty.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user-defined table type, then declare a parameter as that table type.  Then you can pass your orders into that table parameter and use it as you would any other regular table.

```
-- create user-defined table type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ordersUdt] AS TABLE(
    [orderNo] nvarchar(10) NULL
)
GO

-- declare table variable as new type
-- insert order records into table variable
declare @records ordersUdt
insert into @records ([orderNo])
values ('12345'),('34567'),('56789')

-- use table variable as you would regular table
select * 
from orderProperty op
join Corder c
    on op.CorderID = C.id
join @records r
    on R.orderNo = r.orderNo
```

Comment: Thanks for the clue, let me try.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **OPENJSON AND CROSS APPLY**

declare a list of order as JSON format

```
declare  @orderNoList AS varchar(max) = '[1,2,3]'
```

and finally, use cross apply

```
SELECT *
FROM orderProperty OP
INNER JOIN Corder C ON OP.CorderId = C.id
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON(@orderNoList) WHERE C.id = [value]) AS O
```